# Add character into middle of String

Tags: java, regex

I need your help to turn a String like `12345678` into `1234.56.78`

```
[FOUR DIGITS].[TWO DIGITS].[TWO DIGITS]
```

My code:

```
String s1 = "12345678";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d+)", "$1.$2").replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d+)", "$1.$2");
System.out.println(s1);
```

But the result is `12.34.56.78`

Comment: the input is always 8 digits. Is it more expensive to use a regular expression? I tried it with regular expressions because I think it is more effective than concatenation. Sorry, I'm new, I'm trying to do it in the best way.

Comment: Using regex will surely be more expensive than simple substring here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that you'll always have the input in the same format then you can simply use a `StringBuilder` and do something like this:

```
String input = "12345678";
String output = new StringBuilder().append(input.substring(0, 4))
        .append(".").append(input.substring(4, 6)).append(".")
        .append(input.substring(6)).toString();
System.out.println(output);
```

This code creates a new String by appending the dots to the sub-strings at the specified locations.

**Output:**

```
1234.56.78
```

Comment: You don't really need to use StringBuilder, pretty sure javac will automatically decide to use it.

Comment: @SameerPuri I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your comment. If you are saying that we can simply use `+` for the concatenation and it will be optimized later by the compiler then it's true. But it's even better if you take care of things yourself rather than leaving it on the compiler. Well, that's my opinion which might differ from what other people think.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant -- just for simplicity's sake since it would be done by javac anyways. You do have a point though, that behavior could change in the future creating unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method with updated regex otherwise the second [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) call will replace including the first four digits.

```
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d+)", "$1.$2.$3")
```

Answer (score 2):

This puts dots after every pair of chars, *except* the first pair:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(^....)|(..)", "$1$2.");
```

This works for any length string, including odd lengths.

For example

```
"1234567890123" --> "1234.56.78.90.12.3"
```